# linux freeze with pxe when there are more than 1 network interface

Tags: linux, networking, pxe

I have setup 2 virtual machines with virtualbox:

1. the 1st (named server after this) one acts as dhcp (isc-dhcp-server) and tftp (atftpd) server
2. the other one (named "client" after this) as a diskless computer.

The boot process for the client starts with syslinux, which loads a linux kernel passing it the arguments `initrd=ram_test.img nfsroot=10.0.0.1:/srv/nfsroot/stretch,rw ip=dhcp rw`.

The computers are defined as 64bit ones, the server boots on a Debian stable and the client is provided a Debian stable to boot on too.

There are no problems when the client have only 1 network interface (internal network, "intel pro/100MT Desktop (8254OEM)" card type), but as soon as I add another of the same type, with a different MAC address, things go ok until linux tries to fetch DHCP address.

At that point, the system freezes on the phrase "random: fast init done".
The other things I can see before this, and are probably more interesting, are:

```
e1000: enp0s8 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
e1000: enp0s3 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s8: link becomes ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s3: link becomes ready
IP-Config: no response after 2 secs - giving up
IP-Config: enp0s3 hardware address 08:00:27:2a:1a:3b mtu 1500 DHCP
IP-Config: enp0s8 hardware address 08:00:27:5f:de:30 mtu 1500 DHCP
```

After freeze, 323 seconds later, there is only "random: crng init done".

Here is the dhcpd.conf:

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  #range: 10.0.0.0xC0/26
  range 10.0.0.192 10.0.0.250;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  filename "tftp://10.0.0.1/pxelinux.0";
}
```

To make things working (at least, with only 1 interface), I had to modify the file `/srv/nfsroot/stretch/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` to look like this (comments and empty lines removed):

```
MODULES=netboot
BUSYBOX=auto
KEYMAP=fr
COMPRESS=gzip
DEVICE=eth0
NFSROOT=auto
BOOT=nfs
```

I think the problem comes from the arguments provided to kernel in the syslinux configuration, or the `initramfs.conf` but I can't find the exact point on which I'm failing, and searching the web was unsuccessful too.

While writing all this, I noticed the line `DEVICE=eth0` in the `initramfs.conf`, and thought it may be this, but I just tried to alter the linux-kernel parameters to add it `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` so that the kernel uses the old eth0/eth1 names, but the behavior is identical (except, of course, that the names in the logs are no longer enpXsY but ethZ).

The point of having 2 network interfaces in that VM is because that system is intended to deploy systems (through cdebootstrap and manual scripts, already working) on hardware which does have 2 network interfaces. I didn't had the opportunity to try this in real situation, but I'm persuaded that the problem will be there too (why would it not?) so I'd really like to have some opinions here.

Thanks, and sorry for the WoT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the `append` line in your pxelinux cfg file add the option:

```
ipappend 2
```

That will tell the booting kernel to perform the DHCP transaction using the PXE booting NIC

Comment: Going back on this, I had some other issues with different systems (the tests where with virtualbox, with MANO842 motherboard cards I was still having boot problems), but thanks to that info, I was able to find the information I needed on [this page](https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#SYSAPPEND_bitmask). In short, ipappend seems deprecated, use sysappend instead, and it is possible to use BOOTIF=MA:CA:DD:RE:SS:00 to specify which iface has to be used. This might help other having this issue later.

Comment: ipappend is not deprecated. `The SYSAPPEND option, introduced in Syslinux 5.10, is an enhancement of a previous IPAPPEND option which was only available on PXELINUX. `

Answer (score 2):

So, here's the long and short of it...

When booting up a PXE diskless client, if that client happens to have multiple networking interfaces, the kernel may either crash into a kernel panic, or IP-Config will hang.

The reason this happens is because there's a bug in IP-Config and nobody really cares to fix it. Essentially, IP-Config is hitting the DHCP server too quickly and repetitively. Because of that, the DHCP doesn't respond the second (or third) time the IP-Config hits it. Therefore, IP-Config is unable to resolve a DHCP and without an IP, the root directory can't be set up and then the kernel crashes.

The work around is this (if you're using iPXE):

```
kernel ${base-url}vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic boot=nfs netboot=nfs quiet splash panic=30 nfsroot=10.0.0.1/root network ksdevice=bootif BOOTIF=${netX/mac} ip=${ip}:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:::none
initrd ${base-url}initrd.img-4.4.0-43-generic
```

If you're using regular PXE:

```
KERNEL vmlinuz-4.4.0-43-generic 
IPAPPEND 2 
APPEND vga=794 boot=nfs root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-4.4.0-43-generic quiet splash panic=30 -- nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/root ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:::none
```

I don't expect that your entries will look exactly like this. These are just **examples**. So, edit yours accordingly.

1) You need to set a static IP address directly in the kernel params (or the append). If you don't, IP-Config is going to try to run DHCP and **you don't want that**.

2) You want to force PXE to only query from one NIC interface and not from all of them. To force it to only use one interface, you use "network ksdevice=bootif BOOTIF=${netX/mac}" in iPXE and you use "IPAPPEND 2" in regular PXE. Write it exactly as shown above.

That's it! Two easy steps and you'll be on your way.

The BOOTIF forces PXE to only use the primary interface that the PXE was loaded on. It'll ignore all the other interfaces. IPAPPEND does the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the highlights. I've upvoted, but, since I don't have enough reputation... well... Anyway, this explains various things, and I think that pxelinux actually use one of the workarounds you described, namely, the 2nd one.